# How to include headers into a csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file that doesn't include headers. How can I manually add the headers  i.e. add the headers to the top of the file

```
GA, 11
LA, 12
NY, 122
......
```

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Lutz Horn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238541/how-to-include-headers-into-a-csv-file#comment35555447_23238541) pointed out, you can use `csv.writeheader` if you're using py3.2+. If you're using py2.7 like me, maybe this might help:

```
import csv
myHeaders = ["Header1", "Header2"]
csvData = []
with open( 'myfile.csv','r+b' ) as csvfile:
    # Read the data
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(myHeaders)
    writer.writerows([row for row in reader])
```

*Note*: `csv` doesn't have an insert/overwrite row method, so you need to read & write the whole data. Should be trivial for small-to-medium sized files

*Edit:* Previous code would append repeated data to the end of the file

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable`

Comment: No need to load into memory and extend... write the header, then write the data: `writer.writerow(my_headers); writer.writerows(reader)`

Comment: its writing the headers in the row, not at the top

Comment: @JonClements Thanks! Edited the code!
& OP Isn't that what a header is? The *top* row?

Comment: ok, now I get it. Its appending it the the previous file, and then writing the data after it. Thats why I have it in the middle.

Comment: @DevEx: Yeah, sorry about that. Fixed it in the edit! You can change the file name where the `writer` is open to create a copy if you want

Comment: @mogambo you've seriously overcomplicated this now... my comment is literally all the code you need inside your `with` block... open the files, the reader and writer, write the header, write the rows... done - you don't need this `csvData` at all

Comment: @JonClements Using the `writer` in the same `with` as the `reader` caused the data to appended not overwritten. That's why I had to use another `with`. Maybe you have a better solution/edit? :)

Comment: @mogambo the one I've already described... I don't quite understand your difficulty with overwriting and appending..?

Comment: @JonClements Edited. Yeah, I missed your earlier comment. Also, I was getting an error when trying to use `writer.writerows()` but turns out it's an unrelated excel problem. Thanks for the help!